# Prometheus can't scrape custom metrics

Tags: java, prometheus, metrics

I'm trying to set up Prometheus to scrape some custom metrics exposed by a java service with the java lib Prometheus Micrometer. I have no error whatsoever in prometheus log except for `proto: bad wiretype for field io_prometheus_client.MetricFamily.Metric: got wiretype 0, want 2` in the prometheus url http://localhost:9090/targets for this specific job.

I can scrape other metrics from node exporter on the same instance as the java service so it does not seem to be a networking/firewall problem. I can also curl the metrics directly.

The prometheus job conf :

```
  - job_name: 'my_service'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['my_instance:XXXX']
```

I'd like to know if the problem is on prometheus or the java service side and how to solve it.

Comment: Sounds like "misunderstanding" between Prometheus and your exporter. Can it be that you are using old version of Prometheus? Also, are native histograms involved? I recommend you using promtool (located near your prometheus binary) to [check metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/promtool/#promtool-check-metrics)